# Spring Integration with Multiple SFTP Session

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

I am using Spring Intergation's SFTP with Outbound Channel Adapter for uploading files to a remote location.  It works fine when it is sending files to one SFTP location.  However, in my code, I am trying to send to multiple SFTP location based on different criteria.

The following is my set up - following from Spring Intergation doc

```
<beans:bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <beans:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="password"/>
    <beans:property name="port" value="22"/>
    <beans:property name="user" value="user"/>
</beans:bean>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    channel="outputChannel"
    remote-directory="foo/bar"
    use-temporary-filename="false"
    mode="REPLACE"/>
```

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to configure multiple SFTP Session
2. For the outbound channel adapter, is there any way I can set this up in my code instead of XML, specially, I want to calculate the value for remote-directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the [dynamic ftp sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) for a technique to do what you want.

The upcoming 4.2 release (release candidate 1 is now available) has a `DelegatingSessionFactory` where you can dynamically look up the session factory to use. See ["what's new in 4.2"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RC1/reference/html/whats-new.html#_delegating_session_factory).